# New links in default_head_blocks.xml never show up

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

I want to add a few links in a Magento 2 store's `head` element, to serve a favicon bundle (OS specific link icons etc). In my theme directory I've added a new default_head_blocks.xml:

```
./app/design/frontend/MyTheme/std/Magento_Theme/default_head_blocks.xml
```

With following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
```

Problem is, these tags never show up in the html. I've added a `default.xml` in the same folder to remove the standard *Report Bugs* link and that link vanished faster than my salary on a Friday.
I can also browse the image URLs manually to get the icon images. But still, the links never show up.

What am I missing here?

PS. Must point out that the theme inherits *Blank*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The link elements shall have a `src` attribute instead of a `href`. And if one element fails, all fail. This code works:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
     <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" src="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" src="favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
     <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
```

Comment: If you are still having problems check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322495/91580

Comment: No. The answer has been here the last two and a half years.